# Using reference of an array to append the array in a function perl

Tags: arrays, perl, reference

I'm trying to get my head around a perl script. Where a funnction is called with the reference of an array. In this function this array is appended.

So my first question is if I append something to the reference of an array in a function do I append it to the global array?

I tried to boil the script down and tried to be as close to the script as possible. I end up with this perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my @array = ();
my $i = 0;

while ($i < 11) {
    fun(\@array);
    $i++;
}

print @array , "\n";

sub fun {
    my $array_ref = @_;
    push @{$array_ref}, $i;
}
```

The next question would be why does this script not work?
It crashes with this error message:

```
Can't use string ("1") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at trial.pl line 17.
```

Comment: If you `print "@array\n"` then the elements will be nicely separated by spaces in the output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you're seeing is caused by the line

```
 my $array_ref = @_;
```

In scalar context, an ordinary array returns its length, so `$array_ref` is `1`, not a reference to `@array`. In the next line, perl complains because you can't dereference `1`. When assigning from `@_` (or any other array), use list context:

```
 my ($array_ref) = @_;
```

Alternatively, in this case, you can use `shift`:

```
 my $array_ref = shift;
```